# Filling, Printout3D with RegionPlot3D

Tags: regions, 3d-printing

I used RegionPlot3D to generate a model and Printout3D it to an STL file:

```
Block[{f = 3, r = 6, base = 5, l = 15, c = 9, holes, ms},
 holes = Table[((x - c Cos[a])^2 + (y - c Sin[a])^2) > 9, 
  {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, Pi/3}] /. List -> And;
 ms = RegionPlot3D[ z < base + (x^2 + y^2)/(4 f) && holes, 
  {x, -l, l}, {y, -l, l}, {z, 0, base + r^2/(4 f)}];
 Printout3D[ms, "ms6.stl", 
  RegionSize -> Quantity[#, "Millimeters"] & /@ {2 l, 2 l, base + r^2/(4 f) }]
]
```

The plot was successful and the STL file looks normal. Since I need this printout to be strong, in the software for 3D printer, I set the filling percentage to 100%. However, the print out is almost totally empty inside. I realized that it was because the model is indeed empty.

How can I export a filled model, or how should I plot to make the model totally filled inside?

Comment: Try to convert `ms` into a `BoundaryMesh` and use `TriangulateMesh`.

Answer (score 4):

I modified your code slightly, setting `BoxRatios` to `Automatic` so the on-screen display matches the true dimensions, and naming the plot ms.

```
 ms = Block[{f = 3, r = 6, base = 5, l = 15, c = 9, holes, ms}, 
  holes = Table[((x - c Cos[a])^2 + (y - c Sin[a])^2) > 9, 
            {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, Pi/3}] /. List -> And;
  RegionPlot3D[
   z < base + (x^2 + y^2)/(4 f) && holes, 
   {x, -l, l}, {y, -l, l}, {z, 0, base + r^2/(4 f)}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
  ]
```

First discretize your region, producing a `MeshRegion` object that comprises the boundary surface. It is 2-dimensional, as you stated, since it is just the boundary surface of the solid region.

```
dms = DiscretizeGraphics[ms]
```

Using the same data (the vertices and face indices in the `MeshRegion`), change the head to `BoundaryMeshRegion` to get the solid version.

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[dms], MeshCells[dms, 2]]
```

Comment: A method I learned from user21: Use `MeshCells[dms, 2, "Multicells" -> True]`; this should be a bit faster for fine meshes. Apply `TriangulateMesh` if you need a tetrahedral mesh for export.

Comment: Thanks and I shall try tomorrow. (It is midnight over here.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher this option also leaves the indices in a packed array, whereas the default cannot.

Answer (score 2):

STL only supports faces (as opposed to solids), so I'd be surprised if converting to `BoundaryMeshRegion` and triangulating fixed things.

`Printout3D` does some repair with the option `Method -> "PerformModelRepair"` (I believe this is the default setting). In your case, your model comes back repaired:

```
 FindMeshDefects[RepairMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[ms]], All, "Cell"]
```

> ```
> <|"FlippedFaces" -> {}, "HoleEdges" -> {}, "TinyFaces" -> {}, "SingularVertices" -> {},
>   "DanglingEdges" -> {}, "SingularEdges" -> {}, "TinyComponents" -> {}, 
>   "TJunctionEdges" -> {}, "IsolatedVertices" -> {}, "OverlappingFaces" -> {}|>
> ```

As for the external software, it's hard to know what's going wrong, but it sounds like something is preventing it from inferring a solid. Which software are you using?

---

Perhaps a different technique would give a better result.

The highest fidelity method is probably subtracting away the cylinders and paraboliod from the cuboid. We can do this with mesh based boolean operations in 11.2+:

```
δ = .5;
fill = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Cuboid[{-15, -15, 0}, {15, 15, 8}]];

cyls = Table[With[{cx = c Cos[a], cy = c Sin[a]}, Cylinder[{{cx, cy, -1}, {cx, cy, 9}}, 3]], {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, Pi/3}]
dc = RegionUnion @@ (BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, MaxCellMeasure -> .1δ] & /@ cyls);

parab = ImplicitRegion[z > base + (x^2 + y^2)/(4 f), {{x, -l, l}, {y, -l, l}, {z, 0, 8}}];
db = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[parab, MaxCellMeasure -> δ];

model = RegionDifference[RegionDifference[fill, dc], db]
```

[image]

Note the weird artifacts in the paraboloid. I think this is just an issue with rendering multi-cell polygons, as `Normal[Show[mesh]]` renders just fine.

This model is also has no defects:

```
Values @ FindMeshDefects[RepairMesh[model], All, "Cell"]
```

> ```
> {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
> ```

Give this one a try and see if it works.